# Atomikos + Infinispan + Jetty errors

Tags: spring, jetty, atomikos, infinispan

I'm using Spring with hibernate, atomikos and infinispan on jetty. After annotating any entity as @Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.TRANSACTIONAL) following error appears

```
13:24:02.590 [main] WARN  atomikos - atomikos connection pool 'atomikosDataSource': error creating proxy of connection an AtomikosXAPooledConnection with a SessionHandleState with 0 context(s)
com.atomikos.datasource.pool.CreateConnectionException: an AtomikosXAPooledConnection with a SessionHandleState with 0 context(s): connection is erroneous
    at com.atomikos.jdbc.AtomikosXAPooledConnection.testUnderlyingConnection(AtomikosXAPooledConnection.java:114)
    at com.atomikos.datasource.pool.AbstractXPooledConnection.createConnectionProxy(AbstractXPooledConnection.java:68)
    at com.atomikos.datasource.pool.ConnectionPool.borrowConnection(ConnectionPool.java:161)
    at com.atomikos.jdbc.AbstractDataSourceBean.getConnection(AbstractDataSourceBean.java:321)
    at com.atomikos.jdbc.AbstractDataSourceBean.getConnection(AbstractDataSourceBean.java:373)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.LocalDataSourceConnectionProvider.getConnection(LocalDataSourceConnectionProvider.java:82)
    at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SuppliedConnectionProviderConnectionHelper.prepare(SuppliedConnectionProviderConnectionHelper.java:51)
    at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate.execute(SchemaUpdate.java:168)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:375)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1872)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.SessionFactoryBuilderSupport.newSessionFactory(SessionFactoryBuilderSupport.java:607)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.SessionFactoryBuilderSupport.doBuildSessionFactory(SessionFactoryBuilderSupport.java:467)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.SessionFactoryBeanDelegate.afterPropertiesSet(SessionFactoryBeanDelegate.java:110)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AnnotationSessionFactoryBean.java:121)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1479)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1417)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:844)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:786)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:703)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:476)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:84)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:284)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1074)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:295)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:292)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:580)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:913)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:464)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:377)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:278)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:111)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.startContext(ContextHandler.java:549)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.Context.startContext(Context.java:136)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1282)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:518)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:499)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.doStart(HandlerWrapper.java:130)
    at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.doStart(Server.java:224)
    at org.mortbay.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:50)
    at runjettyrun.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:82)
```

It seems that problems lies between atomikos and infinispan. My configuration is based on documentations examples. However in https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/ISPN/Implementing+standalone+JPA+JTA+Hibernate+application+outside+J2EE+server+using+Infinispan+2nd+level+cache they say to add 2 properties to config but what `hibernate.jndi.class`   I can set under jetty?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need this any more since Infinispan 2LC acts as a synchronization rather than an XA resource by default (at least in latest Hibernate 4.0.1 which uses Infinispan 5.1), so I'd revert back any changes you applied from that wiki.